# PHP function converted to variable to be used in HTML email

Tags: php, html

Not sure how to go about this. I have a php function that i would like to pass along in an email. Question is how do I go from this

```
function pmEmailTbl($JobNumber)
{

include('pmconnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT tblUnitMaster.UnitID, tblUnitMaster.JobNumber, tblUnitMaster.Scope, tblJobMaster.JobNumber, tblJobMaster.UnitQty, tblJobMaster.SalesEng, tblJobMaster.PriorityCode, tblJobMaster.SalesNote, tblUnitMaster.JobCode, tblUnitMaster.ModelNumber, tblUnitMaster.RTU FROM tblJobMaster\n"
. "LEFT JOIN tblUnitMaster\n"
. "ON tblJobMaster.JobNumber=tblUnitMaster.JobNumber\n"
. "WHERE tblUnitMaster.JobNumber = '" . $JobNumber . "' ";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

echo "<style>";
echo "th {";
echo "background-color: #6EB4FF;";
echo "color: white;";
echo "}";

echo "</style>";

echo "<table border=2 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=5>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><b><font size=3>"."Job"."</font></b></th>";
echo "<th><b><font size=3>"."Tag"."</font></b></th>";
echo "<th><b><font size=3>"."Model Number"."</font></b></th>";
echo "<th><b><font size=3>"."Sales Eng"."</font></b></th>";
echo "<th><b><font size=3>"."Priority"."</font></b></th>";
echo "<th><b><font size=3>"."Scope"."</font></b></th>";

echo "</tr>";

while ($row=$result->fetch_array())
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><font color=black size=3>",substr($row[0],0,4) , $row[8] , substr($row[0],4,3),"</font></td>"; // Unit Number
    echo "<td><font color=black size=3>".$row[10]."</font></td>"; //RTU Number
    echo "<td><font color=black size=3>".$row[9]."</font></td>"; // Model Number
    echo "<td><font color=black size=3>".$row[5]."</font></td>"; // SalesEng
    echo "<td><font color=black size=3>".$row[6]."</font></td>"; // PriorityCode
    echo "<td><font color=black size=3>".$row[2]."</font></td>"; // Scope

    echo "</tr>";   
    }
echo "</table>";

echo "<br>";

}
```

To something like

```
$EmailTbl = pmEmailTbl($JobNumber)
```

I have no issues with the email, other than the fact that i can not pass the simple table that i would like to. I'm trying to avoid sending the table as an attachment.

*EDIT*

This is the code for the email. this works just as it should.

```
$JobNumber=1111;
$JobCode='F';
$SalesNote='Sales note for job handoff';
$quote='Forest Quote';
$JobNumberCode = substr($JobNumber,0,4) . $JobCode ;

$to = '';

$headers['From'] = 'forest';
$headers['Subject'] = $JobNumberCode . " Job Handoff";

// create MIME object
$mime = new Mail_mime;

// add body parts
$html = '<html><body><p>Job: '  . $JobNumber . ' has been handed off from sales.</p>
<p>Please review and assign an Engineer as soon as possible.</p>


<table border=2 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=10>

<tr>
<th><b><font color=STEELBLUE size=3>Note</font></b></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font color=black size=2>' . $SalesNote . '</font></td>
</tr>  

</table>

<p>Visit master record for Job info.</p>

<p>Thank You,</p>
<p>FOREST</p>
<p>' . $quote . '</p>
</body></html>';

$mime->setHTMLBody($html);

// get MIME formatted message headers and body
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$body = $mime->get();

@$message =& Mail::factory('mail');
$message->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: You're not actually doing anything to **send** an E-mail with this script. Are you asking how you would send an E-mail containing this dynamically-created table?

Comment: take a look at this lib https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm very much aware that that script is not sending the email. That script is simply for the table. like i said i have no issues with the email. The issue is the email does not have the table i want to have in it.

Comment: There's nothing immediately obviously 'wrong' with the creation of the table above (apart from the carriage returns in `$sql`); it should output a table successfully. Can you please update your question so that it also shows how your E-mails are created?

Comment: @ObsidianAge See edit for Email code

Comment: @ObsidianAge The table is created as it should be. The issue is sending said table in the body of the email. separately both parts work as they should. only issue is getting the table in the body of the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `pmEmailTable` is using `echo` statements to build the table.  Those need to be changed to storing the created strings inside a variable which you then return at the end of your function.

**Example**

```
function pmEmailTbl($JobNumber)
{
    // Skipped to first use of echo to start example
    $table = "<style>"; // Here you start by replacing your first echo with $table =
    $table .= "th {";  // You will notice here that we use $table .= to replace echo
    $table .= "background-color: #6EB4FF;"; // .= will concatenate your new string
    $table .= "color: white;"; //to the end of the existing variable
    $table .= "}";
    // Keep replacing echos till you get to the last one
    return $table; //This you add at the end of the function to return the  table
}
```

I've snipped a bunch out for brevity, but basically this is what you are missing.  Currently you are using echo.  All echo does is printout some content.  Here in your case, you want to store that content into a variable that you can then [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) at the end of your function.  That way your function can be used the way you want to call it `$EmailTbl = pmEmailTbl($JobNumber)`, and you will have the table generated then stored in `$EmailTbl`

Comment: Can you explain this more?

Comment: Certainly, I would be more then happy to!  I've updated my answer to detail it out a bit more for you @elliottdan

Comment: Thank you for that. only issue I am having now, I am getting the Job number randomly in the last column. See image  http://imgur.com/a/oznx4 Other than that the table was sent in the email just as I wanted.